# Android Binding SQLite to GridView in Eclipse

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview, listadapter, simplecursoradapter

I have made the following code to retrive data from SQLite database.

```
public Cursor fetchAllScores() {
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_PLAYDATE, KEY_NUMVALA, KEY_NUMVALB }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
}
```

Then I call this function in my main.java file using the following

```
cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllScores();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

After having cursor I manage to populate myGridView with some data using following code

```
GridView myGV = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    String[] cols = new String[] { scoreDbAdapter.KEY_PLAYDATE, scoreDbAdapter.KEY_NUMVALA, scoreDbAdapter.KEY_NUMVALB};
    int[]   views = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, cols, views);

    Log.w("NumRows",adapter.getCount() + "");

    myGV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now the problem is only first row is populated and first two columns, I want data like in forst row (2011-10-27 , 5 , 6 ) and second row like (2011-10-26 , 3 , 2 ) but i m getting is only forst row like (2011-10-27, 2011-10-26 ).

Can this be fixed in GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new layout which contains textViews. Find the layout as shown in first line of the code below and attach your data to the listView. ListView loads the layout containing textView.

```
private void populateGrid()
{

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Cursor c = dbHelper.fetchAllScores();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] cols = new String[] { TodoDbAdapter.KEY_PLAYDATE, TodoDbAdapter.KEY_NUMVALA, TodoDbAdapter.KEY_NUMVALB};
    int[]   views = new int[] { R.id.txt_date, R.id.txt_no, R.id.txt_yes};

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listviewtemp, c, cols, views);

    Log.w("NumRows",adapter.getCount() + "");

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

R.layout.listviewtemp is the listView template layout (separate xml), lv is the listview found in the mainlayout.xml.

```
public Cursor fetchAllScores() {
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_PLAYDATE, KEY_NUMVALA, KEY_NUMVALB }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, take a look here, [Binding to Data with AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html).

Note: Below decription is just example for how to bind cursor to an adapter.

**Filling the Layout with Data**

Inserting data into the layout is typically done by binding the AdapterView class to an Adapter, which retrieves data from an external source (perhaps a list that the code supplies or query results from the device's database).

The following code sample does the following:

1.Creates a Spinner with an existing View and binds it to a new ArrayAdapter that reads an array of colors from the local resources.

2.Creates another Spinner object from a View and binds it to a new SimpleCursorAdapter that will read people's names from the device contacts (see Contacts.People).

```
 // Get a Spinner and bind it to an ArrayAdapter that 

 // references a String array.

Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(    this, R.array.colors,
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

s1.setAdapter(adapter);

// Load a Spinner and bind it to a data query.
private static String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { People._ID, People.NAME};

Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
Cursor cur = managedQuery(People.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null);

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cur,new String[] {People.NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Note that it is necessary to have the People._ID column in projection used with CursorAdapter or else you will get an exception.

If, during the course of your application's life, you change the underlying data that is read by your Adapter, you should call notifyDataSetChanged(). This will notify the attached View that the data has been changed and it should refresh itself.

For more info look at this,

[Custom CursorAdapters](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/).

Thanks.