# display data in grid view

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to display data in grid view from mysql database  using json parser.
I can display static image and text but I don't know how to display from database .
I have googled  but not getting any example.

Comment: query from data base and make an Arraylist and populate it on gridView adapter.

Comment: I am using custom grid view by extending base adapter

Comment: yes so you can do it what is the issue in it ?

Comment: I doubt that you tried to use [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139531/read-data-from-database-and-show-it-in-gridview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

query the database, save in a list then give that list to your adapter.
Finally, give the adapter to the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

First of all; Where is your database ? Which one do you use sqlite or mysql etc. ? 
I will answer them for you have a mysql database.

```
CREATE TABLE 'test'.'pic' (
     ...
    'img' LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('idpic')
)
```

You can create image column table with above code. After create the table and add image to this table(you can add with phpmyadmin) or

```
INSERT INTO xx_BLOB(ID,IMAGE) 
VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('E:/Images/yourimage.png'));
```

you can use above query to add image

You should take image from database with `base64_encode` you can write a php file to retrive image from database.Below php code help for this.

```
<?php

  mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
  mysql_select_db("yourdb");
  $sql=mysql_query("select image from yourtable");

  $i=0;

  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {     
//Where Image Exists.First taking path from database and then image from folder against that  path and then //converting it ino base64 and then Json
   $output[$i]['image']= base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://your ip address/ess/uploads/default/products/".$row['image']));
  $i++;
}
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

This php code return your image with `base64_encode` format than you can parse with [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) libray in your android code. I hope this answer may help you.